# How to get a vertical range element (slider) for Firefox by createElement?

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, range

I **can** successfully create a **vertical** range (slider) for Firefox by directly coding HTML tags:

```
<input type="range" id="s1" orient="vertical" style=""></input> <!-- this creates a vertical slider -->
```

But when I try to do the same by createElement the slider is **horizontal** regardless of any css styles:

```
    var x = document.createElement("INPUT");
    x.type = "range";
    x.id = "s2";
    x.orient = "vertical";
    document.getElementById("div1").appendChild(x); // this creates a horizontal slider
```

The reason I want to do it by script is that I need an array of sliders.

Answer (score 1):

```
x.setAttribute('orient','vertical');
```

see [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mt382861/nnuxy77m/)

Comment: @Udo D : your welcome , you can vote up or set it as accepted instead :)